# Spring security stateless brute force protection against credential guessing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to ignore authentication attempts from an ip address after a number of failed attempts, in order to prevent credential guessing.

There are multiple blog posts about spring security brute force protection. But all of them, I found, suggested an in memory solution, such as following:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

The application I work on is stateless but needs to provide brute force protection. What would be a reasonable way to implement this?

Comment: The sample shows how to do it... Just create a different implementation of the `LoginAttemptService` which stores it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described in the article keeps the number of login attempts in memory, as you noted. I would argue that you can (and should) still do that in a stateless application. "Stateless" typically refers to not using an HTTP Session on the server to track any user state between HTTP request.

There is just no way to keep track of HTTP requests without using some memory on the server. I wouldn't worry about whether that fits the definition of "stateless".

We're using a very similar approach (inspired by the same article) to prevent brute force login attempts in an otherwise completely stateless Spring REST service and it works well for us.

Edit: I could think of one other approach: You could use fail2ban to parse your application logs and (temporarily) ban malicious IP addresses on a "lower" level.

Comment: The problem is that this approach suggest saving the attempts in memory. After and application  restart all failed attempts would be lost. I'll most likely have to save them to a database.

Comment: You're right, if you want to permanently ban users, you probably need to save them to a DB. (We only ban users for short times - 24h - anyway, so it's OK for us that bans don't last after an application restart.)

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic is right, but here ir not a good suggestion under tat conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to try to implement firewall functionality in an application server. Use the logging facilities available to you to log the fact that you're seeing login failures and from which address they are coming from.

Then use the facilities provided by dedicated firewall applications to parse the information you have logged to raise alerts and block addresses. On Linux, fail2ban is an excellent little utility that can watch your logs and create iptables rules to lock hackers out. iptables is an interface to the Linux kernel firewall.